# Programmatically training SSAS data models

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-mining, openquery, dmx-ssas

I am a T-SQL programmer and would like to create and train a model in my SQL Server SSAS data mining structure in a T-SQL stored procedure. I know that I can pass in SELECT DMX queries through linked server (OPENQUERY) but how can I use the DMX CREATE or INSERT queries from T-SQL?

Comment: I have used SSIS to solve it

Comment: Yes it's good, but I need to use it in T-SQL code and need more progamability. Thanks.

Comment: good question but try to provide solutions or steps that you have already tried. I am stuck on a similar issue and have yet to resolve it.

Comment: I have tried using a linked server and then passing DMX through and OPENQUERY query. My colleague modified the linked server settings and set up RPC and RPC_out options to TRUE. He was able to run DMX' DDL queries like CREATE or INSERT to SSAS server after that.